# Supabase Session Null/Undefined Even After Successful Authentication

Tags: node.js, express, supabase, supabase-js

I have an Express server that right now signs into Supabase. The authentication is successful as when I print `data` it gives me the user and session information. But when I try to retrieve the user or session information, it's just null. In the below code, `event` becomes INITIAL_SESSION, `session` becomes null, and `user` also becomes null. I also don't really understand how Supabase's sessions work. I would gladly appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this.

```
app.post("/login", async(req, res) => {
    const {data, error} = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    })
    await supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
        console.log(event, session);
    })
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(401).send("Email/password combination is wrong.");
    }
    else {
        const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
        console.log(user);
        res.status(202).send("Login successful.");
    }
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't be requesting `getUser` in this code since you already have the `session` sent back in the data object on sign in which means you are signed in. There are missing parts to this code as it doesn't show now you are initiating the supabase client. The client initiation behaves differently when in a server environment compare to a client environment.

Answer (score 1):

Supabase enables Email confirmation by default before signing users in. The way I fixed it was by going into Authentication > Providers > Email and unselecting "Confirm email".

Comment: holy puck, you saved my life